# Character Issue in mails sent from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

In Sales cloud, we've a VF page where we've a custom object's field (Rich Text Field) and we're copy pasting texts from word doc having bullet points and includes special characters to it. We've a "Submit" button and on click of it, we'll create a record in sales cloud and send an email to a contact via Marketing Cloud. So, on click of "Submit" button, i can see texts as same as copy pasted content from word in detail page of the record.
Now comes the issue. We're fetching this field's value through amp script in MC email to send this to external contact. We're able to successfully send the email but the email body, wherein we're referring the above field having special characters (',")/bullet points are turning to "???". Can anyone suggest a work around for this? Where exactly the issue is? I dont think its from SC as i can see the same copy pasted text in detail page.

Answer (score 1):

Made it work!

Just tweaked property of email from settings to UTF-8. The main thing is, when you make a change to email content/property settings (config), you must re-start the job (triggered send/ any other job) which uses that email. Then only the changes will come into effect. In my case, triggered send, i can re-start (pause/re-start) from MC directly or i can go to Sales Cloud and de-activate/activate triggered send. It perfectly worked for me.

Thanks, V

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the same that is mentioned in the developer forum: [https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008pwqIAA]

when you copy a test from website or mail, special characters are also copied and saved in the salesforce as HTML characters. These special characters are not visble in the page layout. Since marketing cloud email templates renders the contents as HTML, these characters are displayed in the mail. There is no technical solution for this and the above link has couple workarounds for this with user training.

Answer (score 0):

You will get anomalies in SFMC if you copy your text from Word, etc, and it has special characters.  It's best to copy your text into a plain text editor (eg Notepad, SublimeText) and paste it from there.